# Will there be a problem if bdiff and pdiff are slightly different?

Tags: difficulty, mining-pool-shares

Considering bitcoin target is `0x00000000FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` and pool target is `0x00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. Won't pool miner miss the valid block if it hashes to `0x00000000FFFF100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`? Basically this block is valid according to bitcoin target but not pool target. I'm reading https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty

Answer (score 2):

pdiff, the pool difficulty, is *not* just a different encoding of the same difficulty. Pools set a different (lower) difficulty so that miners can send them more blocks as shares, and calculate how much work they're doing. Valid blocks are still checked against the normal bdiff before submission to the network